# BQ audit logs sink set automatically for a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

Each time we create a new project and use BQ in a project, we need manually to set BQ logs sink, including the filter:

[example of BQ logs sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXNb.png)

[filter of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtfL.png)

The question - is there a way to automate it, once BQ resource is created for a new project, it would create a sink automatically?
It should have:

Sink name: BQLogsDataset_[ProjectNameOrID]

Destination: bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/billing/datasets/BQLogsDataset

Writer identity: would create an appropriate one

Would apply filter: resource.type="bigquery_resource" logName="projects/[ProjectNameOrID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"

May someone implemented similar already or have any other solutions how do not forgot to enable BQ logging every time a new project having BQ resource is created?

thank you!

Comment: Hello I was checking the documentation and according to the documentation, BigQuery automatically sends audit logs to Stackdriver Logging. Then you can export or filter them. Link:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - use this command below to set sink for a project (and child items underneath). BQ logs will be filtered accordingly as well:

```
gcloud logging sinks create <My-sink-name> bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/<My-billing-project-ID>/datasets/<My-dataset-name> --include-children --log-filter='resource.type="bigquery_resource" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access"' --organization=<My-organization-ID>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the Bigquery Sink at the Organization level and enable `--include-children` flag which will configure all the projects in an Organization.

Sample gcloud command:

```
gcloud logging sinks create my-org-bq-sink bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my-gcp-project/datasets/my_bq_audit_dataset --include-children --organization=MY_ORG_ID
```

More details about this gcloud command [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/create)

If you are using Terraform, then you can use [google_logging_organization_sink](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/logging_organization_sink.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this will creates each sink for a all projects under let say organization level, so it is good. But how it later apply the filter by ProjectID mentioned at the initial message?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use organization level sink which can be defined via API. Reference to the API can be found in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/exporting-logs)

This is the relevant description from the documentation talking about the setup:

> A parent resource—a project, folder, billing account, or organization where in which the sink is created. The sink can only export logs belonging to the parent resource. The parents have the following formats:
>
> "projects/[PROJECT_ID]"
>   "organizations/[ORGANIZATION_ID]"
>   "folders/[FOLDER_ID]"
>   "billingAccounts/[BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID]"
>
> An include children parameter. This is only relevant to sinks within organizations. See Aggregated exports.

Note: This setting currently can be done ONLY via API and not via the google console UI

Comment: but does it work with filtering the logs? i.e. now we export only logs matching the filter on a project " resource.type="bigquery_resource" logName="projects/[ProjectNameOrID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" ". How it will add every project ProjectID in the filter?